# How do I programmatically make this auto layout?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

How do I make the label auto layout for all devices.

```
        golabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(30, 100, 350, 100))
        golabel.text = "Game Over"
        golabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        golabel.font = UIFont(name: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Thin" , size: 70)
        self.view.addSubview(golabel)
```

Comment: Autolayout is about placing your view in relation to other views. If you don't explain how it should place in relation with your interface is impossible to give you an answer

Comment: I want it placed just above the center

Comment: X or Y center? or both?

Answer (score 1):

```
let golabel = UILabel()

golabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: golabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 30)
view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)

let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: golabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
view.addConstraint(verticalConstraint)

let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: golabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 350)
golabel.addConstraint(widthConstraint)

let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: golabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
golabel.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
```

Answer (score 0):

After you added the label as a subview you need to avoid autolayout to convert autoresizing masks into constraints or you will probably have conflicts.

```
golabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
```

Here you add the constraints

```
 let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: golabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    self.view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)

let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: golabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    self.view.addConstraint(verticalConstraint)
```

Since you are not adding constraints that inhibit the label to grow the label will use its intrinsic content size, thus it can grow indefinitely based on the length and font of the text.